# Matplotlib overlaying imshow and pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to overlay a pie chart over radial gradient as a background. It does work, but I want the figure to show the entire radial gradient (without the figure boundary being cut as a square).

How do I acheive this?

I want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z7Y4.png) to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1el5.png)

Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


delta = 0.02
x = y = np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.imshow(-X**2+-Y**2, interpolation='bicubic', cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                origin='lower',extent=[-1.2, 1.2, -1.2, 1.2])

plt.pie([1]       , explode=None, radius=1.2          \
                                , labels=['H']        \
                                , labeldistance=0.9   \
                                , startangle=270      \
                                , colors=[g(0.70)])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to get this to work in the same axes. Better create two axes, one for the background image and one for the pie. This allows to tweak them individually, i.e. the background axes should range over the complete figure and have an adjustable aspect ratio, while the pie axes should have some margins and an equal aspect.

The following is an example that positions the pie chart (`ax`) on top of the imshow plot (`ax2`).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(.1,.1,.9,.9)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.pie([1,2], radius=1.2 , labels=['H',"A"] , labeldistance=0.9, 
            startangle=270 , colors=[plt.cm.Blues(1.), plt.cm.Blues(0.5)])

ax2 = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1], zorder=-1)
ax2.axis("off")

w,h = fig.get_size_inches()
x = np.linspace(-1, 1)*w/h
y = np.linspace(-1, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax2.imshow(-X**2-Y**2, interpolation='bicubic', cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                origin='lower', aspect="auto", vmin=-0.99)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works, but I want to see the entire radial gradient (as in I want the whole gradient circle to be shown in the figure). I did try tweaking the code, but it does not seem to be working as I intended... Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What is shown *is* the entire gradient on the defined grid. I have no clue what you don't like about it as this is how you define your data.

Comment: what I am saying is I want something like this [https://imgur.com/a/Tburo ] instead of something like this [https://imgur.com/a/QZDjl ]

Comment: You may sure define your data differently, e.g. use an exponential function. Or you may choose a different `vmin` that matches your desired outcome.